# ¿Cómo optimizo mi VPS de Hostinger para que no le afecte la concurrencia?

Tags: vps

soy nuevo en informatica y me gustaría ayuda sobre cómo mejorar el rendimiento en mi VPS para que la concurrencia de usuarios no lo afecte.

Agradeceré el apoyo y asistencia de ustedes con una donación.

Graciasª

Answer (score -1):

La verdad es que tu pregunta es demasiado generica.

La concurrencia puede estar afectando el software (por ejemplo, webserver, php, mariadb), o el hardware (memoria, cpu, swap)

No es lo mismo un CMS generico, que uno realizado a medida, o incluso que tener un sitio estatico.

Tampoco aclaras qué tipo de uso le das al VPS (uso específico de una empresa para realizar X tarea, un proceso, etc) o si tienes paginas web de uso comercial, pruebas).

Es necesario conocer más detalles, incluso los usuarios concurrentes que tienes

Comment: Hola user319660, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos.